# Wordcloud - relative font size amongst multiple instances?

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

I'm using `wordcloud==1.8.1` to render a plot with multiple wordclouds,
each one beeing a bar in a bar chart.

Basically just adding some subplots like this:

```
subplot = plt.subplot(1, len(ontologies), i, anchor='S')
subplot.set_title(title, size=10, y=-0, pad=-25)
subplot.set_ymargin(50)
plt.plot()
cloud = WordCloud(
    font_path=f'{current_dir}/assets/source-sans-pro.ttf',
    background_color='white',
    width=width,
    height=height,
    # max_words=30,
    prefer_horizontal=0.99,
    color_func=lambda *args, **kwargs: colors[ontology_name]
)
plt.imshow(cloud.generate_from_frequencies(
    frequencies
    #max_font_size=200,
    #min_font_size=10,
))
plt.axis("off")
```

Is there a possibility to get the relative font-sizes correct amongst **all of the** wordclouds? A the moment those are only relative to each other inside the same wordcloud.

I tried dynamically setting `min_font_size` and `max_font_size` based on the frequencies, but those just do not seem to affect the relations...

So if a word appears 10x more often than any other in the document, i'd like to have it 10 times larger in font than all other words. no matter in which wordcloud.

`frequencies` would just be dicts with the total words occurrences:

wordcloud 1 (200x400) `{'word1': 10, 'word2': 40}`
wordcloud 2 (200x600) `{'word3': 20, 'word4': 80}`
wordcloud 2 (200x800) `{'word5': 40, 'word6': 160}`

So, how to create 3 wordclouds from this an keep the proportions, so that `word6` in wordcloud 3 is 16x larger than `word1` in wordcloud 1?

[image]

Comment: You don't define `frequencies` in your snippet, but presumably you can change the populations in each frequency so that they all normalize to the same thing.  There is also `relative_scaling` which you could perhaps modify depending on the population.

Comment: You should set `relative_scaling` to `1`, so that the font size is directly proportional to the frequency (per document). Default is `0.5` which determins the font size from both frequency and rank, see [source](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/35ce9b781d3bd5c25ea178edd662b0f6dde9d065/wordcloud/wordcloud.py#L494-L495). With `1` the second summand becomes zero.

Comment: thank you very much. 
So then i'd just have to scale the frequencies according to the current wordcloud dimensions?

Comment: (updated the questions with some more data...)

Comment: It turns out that this doesn't seem to be possible, as [`generate_from_frequencies`](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/35ce9b781d3bd5c25ea178edd662b0f6dde9d065/wordcloud/wordcloud.py#L391) doesn't take *frequencies* but *counts* and internally calculates the frequencies relative to the word with the highest count in the dict, so you can't scale the different word count dicts relative to each other. I deleted my wrong comments above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result for the toy example but I'm not 100 % sure if this holds true for larger sets when the image gets more crowded and it will most probably fail for the vertical bars in your example (maybe setting `prefer_horizontal` to a low value of say `0.1` may help in this case, rotating most of the words).

The following has to be paid attention to:

- set `relative_scaling` to `1` so that the font size is directly proportional to the frequency (per document).
- make the images wide enough so that the largest word will fit in its entire length into the image (otherwise is may get shrunk)
- set `font_step` to `0` to prevent font decreasing if the word doesn't fit at the first try (see [source](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/35ce9b781d3bd5c25ea178edd662b0f6dde9d065/wordcloud/wordcloud.py#L516-L524))

The following example illustrates this (colors and word positions are chosen randomly, so your result will be different, but the sizes and size ratios should be the same as in the example output) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wordcloud

wl1 = {'word1': 10, 'word2': 40}
wl2 = {'word3': 20, 'word4': 80}
wl3 = {'word5': 40, 'word6': 160}

# get max word count per list
w1 = max((v for k,v in wl1.items()))
w2 = max((v for k,v in wl2.items()))
w3 = max((v for k,v in wl3.items()))

# get total max for scaling factor among lists
w_max = max(w1, w2, w3)

height = 400
kwargs = {'relative_scaling': 1, 'height': height, 'width': 4*height,
          'prefer_horizontal': 1, 'font_step': 0 }

wc1 = (wordcloud.WordCloud(**kwargs)
       .generate_from_frequencies(wl1, max_font_size=w1/w_max*height))
wc2 = (wordcloud.WordCloud(**kwargs)
       .generate_from_frequencies(wl2, max_font_size=w2/w_max*height))
wc3 = (wordcloud.WordCloud(**kwargs)
       .generate_from_frequencies(wl3, max_font_size=w3/w_max*height))


fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, layout='constrained', figsize=(10,8))
for ax, wc in zip(axes.flat, (wc1, wc2, wc3)):
    ax.imshow(wc.to_image())
    ax.axis('off')
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, i guess this as close as you can get with that library - thank you!